# Test(Mocking) a void function which internally calls other functions that create connection with database

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito, powermockito

I have a class in which there is a private variable Connection. I want to test functionA for which i have to mock functionB and functionC.

I tried it using powermock and mockito but not able to do it.

What should be exactly done to test fucntionA and to mock functionB and functionC.

```
public class ToMock {

    private Connection connection;

    private static functionA(String name) {       
        // do something    
        functionB()    
        return xyz;
    }

    public static void functionB() {
         connection = functionC("localhost", 10000);    
    }

    public static void functionC(String hostName, int port) {
        //make a connection to db

        String connectionString = String.format("jdbc:hive2://%s:%d/",emrHost, port);

        LOGGER.info("Connection string {}", connectionString);

        try {

            Class.forName("org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver");    
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString, "hadoop", "");

            LOGGER.info("Connected successfully");

            return con;    
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw Throwables.propagate(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could move the connection creation part out into a new factory class and then mock only that class. That way you also keep your logic independent of the database connection creation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refactor your code like @neurotic-d describes. Something like this:

```
public class ToMock {

    private Connection connection;

    public ToMock(Connection connection){
        this.connection = connection;
    }

    private functionA(String name) {       
        // do something    

        return xyz;
    }
}  



public class ToMockFactory {

    public static ToMock toMock(){
        return new ToMock(functionB());
    }

    public static Connection functionB() {
        return functionC("localhost", 10000);    
    }

    public static Connection functionC(String hostName, int port) {
        //make a connection to db

        String connectionString =     String.format("jdbc:hive2://%s:%d/",emrHost, port);

        LOGGER.info("Connection string {}", connectionString);

        try {

            Class.forName("org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver");    
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString,   "hadoop", "");

            LOGGER.info("Connected successfully");

            return con;    
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw Throwables.propagate(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you have `static` methods. So you cannot use Mockito by its design. You could use PowerMock. 
See usage here : [Link](https://github.com/jayway/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage).

See here : [link](https://dzone.com/articles/using-powermock-mock-static).

Basically code that will look like this(Copied from PowerMock examples),

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Static.class)
public class YourTestCase {
@Test
public void testMethodThatCallsStaticMethod() {
    // mock all the static methods in a class called "Static"
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(Static.class);
    // use Mockito to set up your expectation
    Mockito.when(Static.firstStaticMethod(param)).thenReturn(value);
    Mockito.when(Static.secondStaticMethod()).thenReturn(123);

    // execute your test
    classCallStaticMethodObj.execute();

    // Different from Mockito, always use PowerMockito.verifyStatic() first
    // to start verifying behavior
    PowerMockito.verifyStatic(Mockito.times(2));
    // IMPORTANT:  Call the static method you want to verify
    Static.firstStaticMethod(param);


    // IMPORTANT: You need to call verifyStatic() per method verification, 
    // so call verifyStatic() again
    PowerMockito.verifyStatic(); // default times is once
    // Again call the static method which is being verified 
    Static.secondStaticMethod();

    // Again, remember to call verifyStatic()
    PowerMockito.verifyStatic(Mockito.never());
    // And again call the static method. 
    Static.thirdStaticMethod();
}
}
```

Here `Static` is the class to which the static method(s) belongs.